# "User error" pattern matching failure when using getArgs

Tags: haskell

```
import Control.Concurrent (forkIO)
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main= do
    [a,b]<- getArgs
    putStrLn $ "command line arguments: " ++ show [a,b]
```

When I compiled it, it was all right, but when I ran it,
it said "user error (Pattern match failure in do expression)", what is wrong here?

Comment: Did you run the program with only two arguments?

Comment: Yes, I only need two arguments

Comment: It's obvious that you _need_ two arguments, but did you execute this program with two arguments passed in at the command line?

Comment: Yes, now I know your meaning. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're pattern matching `[a, b]` on the return value of `getArgs`.  If you run your program with anything other than 2 arguments, then the return value will not match the pattern `[a, b]`.  So unless you run this program as

```
$ ./xie 1 2
command line arguments: ["1","2"]
```

It will throw an error.  Instead, if you wrote your code

```
main = do
    args <- getArgs
    case args of
        [a, b] -> putStrLn $ "command line arguments: " ++ show [a, b]
        _      -> putStrLn "Invalid number of arguments"
```

then you would never fail on a pattern match.

Answer (score 4):

The pattern `[a,b]` only matches a 2-element list, so if `getArgs` returns a list with a different number of elements, the match will fail.

When using `do` notation, when a match fails, the `fail` function is called, which in the case of `IO` causes a `userError` to be thrown.